# Eclipse Maven Project Won't Run With Hibernate-Core Dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, m2e

I'm trying to run a basic Hello World Maven project in Eclipse Mars, but as soon as I add a hibernate-core dependency into pom.xml, the console gives me this error:

```
Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  javaw [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
   -d32   use a 32-bit data model if available
   -d64   use a 64-bit data model if available
   -server    to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server.

-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
              A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
              and ZIP archives to search for class files.
-D<name>=<value>
              set a system property
-verbose:[class|gc|jni]
              enable verbose output
-version      print product version and exit
-version:<value>
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              require the specified version to run
-showversion  print product version and continue
-jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
              Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
              in a future release.
              include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
-? -help      print this help message
-X            print help on non-standard options
-ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              enable assertions with specified granularity
-da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
-disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
              disable assertions with specified granularity
-esa | -enablesystemassertions
              enable system assertions
-dsa | -disablesystemassertions
              disable system assertions
-agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
              see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
-agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
              load native agent library by full pathname
-javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
              load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
-splash:<imagepath>
              show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

The dependency definition in pom.xml looks like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>
        com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.hibernate
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.19.Final-patched-play-1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

When I searched for 'hibernate core' in the Select Dependency dialogue, that was the only version that came up.

Comment: Use rather this page to find POM dependencies: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core This is POM for 4.2.19 version: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.19.Final      `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.19.Final</version>
</dependency>`  Your groupid is wrong.

Comment: Have tried that. Still getting the same error. I have tried numerous versions.